# NVIDIA Docker CUDA>=11.0 does not have NSight compute Cli for kernel profiling on Ampere GPU

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I found that when  I pull NVIDIA Docker from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/cuda/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) with CUDA>=11.0 and Ubuntu>=18.04, it does not comes with Nsight Compute (`ncu`) for kernel profiling. It only comes with `nvprof` would not work if I am profiling on an A100 or RTX3090.

Is there any way to solve this problem? For example, install `ncu` separately?

Comment: Let's keep the gratuitous text formatting to a minimum, OK? And which docker container are you using, *exactly*?

Comment: nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-nsight-compute-in-containers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, install ncu separately?

You can install Nsight Compute by itself.  See [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-compute).